# How to make can.Model send JSON data when update?

Tags: javascript, javascriptmvc, canjs, canjs-model

I have this code:

```
var SotriesModel = can.Model.extend({
    findAll: 'GET /api/stories/',
    create: function(story) {
        console.log(story)
        return $.ajax({
            url: '/api/stories/',
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            data: JSON.stringify(story)
        });
    },
    update : function(story) {
        console.log(story)
        return $.ajax({
            url: '/api/stories/',
            type: 'PUT',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            data: JSON.stringify(story)
        });
    },
    destroy: 'DELETE /api/stories/{id}'
}, {});
var story = new SotriesModel({id:123123, name:"test"});
story.save();
```

What I expect from save is a PUT request with a JSON in payload, but what I get is just the id number:

```
123123
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [update method signature](http://canjs.com/docs/can.Model.update.html#sig_can_Model_update_function_id_serialized___can_Deffered) for using a function is `can.Model.update: function(id, serialized) -> can.Deffered`.

So as the first parameter you always get the id and as the second the serialized data.

Changing your `update : function(story) {}` to `update : function(id, story) {}` should solve the problem.